# how to stop horizontal scrolling in case of long press

Tags: android

I have a horizontal list of images. I want, if I long press the image and try to drag the image then...

Comment: Incomplete question......write complete question. Or you must be clear with your question

Comment: Your question is incomplete and borders on incomprehensible. Please consider revising it.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the Gallery class and override the onLongPress(MotionEvent e) method and where so ever you are placing Gallery view in the xml place your class instead.

Like the following

```
package com.prac;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyGallery extends Gallery {


private Context mContext;

public MyGallery(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MyGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mContext = context;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MyGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}



@Override
public boolean onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
      {
            // do what ever you want on Long Press Here
    return false;
  }

 }
```

Now  your xml layout should be like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >

 <com.prac.MyGallery
 android:id="@+id/Gallery"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps :) And if it helps you out dont forget to accept the answer by clicking the arrow on left side of answer and making it green